# What sort orders items by alternating between placing an item at the start or end of the list?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I have an ordered list, largest to smallest.

```
{ 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 }
```

I want a list like this

```
{ 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }
```

If you can see, the new order is, first by each odd index ascending, then by each even index descending.

The idea is that each half of the list has roughly the same weight. e.g

```
{ 10, 8, 6, 4, 2 } = 30
{ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 } = 25
```

The title is the best I can explain in a sentence what I'm looking for which is why I had trouble finding the answer from Google.

Here is my go in C#. I'll welcome any comment on my attempt but I'm only looking of the algorithms name, if it has one.

```
var firstHalf = new List<string>();
var secondHalf = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < originalList.Count; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 1)
    {
        firstHalf.Add(originalList[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        secondHalf.Add(originalList[i]);
    }
}

secondHalf.Reverse();

var finalList = new List<string>(firstHalf);
finalList.AddRange(secondHalf);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're doing, but it's similar to the partition problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most efficient way, but it's easy:

```
var yourlist = originalList.Where(i => i % 2 == 0)
                           .OrderBy(i => i)
                           .Concat(originalList.Where(i => i % 2 != 0)
                                               .OrderByDescending(i => i))
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: I posted my solution as an aid to understanding how list is ordered. I'm asking for the name of the algorithm not another solution. Thanks anyway.